# bbPress RTX integration

Tags: php, sql, janrain, bbpress, rtx

Im currently working on a RTX/Janrain integration with bbPress, but im stuck with a SQL query which doesnt give me any results even though I've been trying with wildcards and an e-mail adress i know is registered.

> Sign In
>
> $rpxApiKey = 'xxxxx';
>
> if(isset($_POST['token'])) {    /*
>   STEP 1: Extract token POST parameter
>   */    $token = $_POST['token'];
>
> /* STEP 2: Use the token to make the
>   auth_info API call */     $post_data =
>   array('token' => $_POST['token'],
>                        'apiKey' => $rpxApiKey,
>                        'format' => 'json');
>
> $curl = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt($curl,
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,
>   'https://rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info');
>   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
>   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,
>   false);   curl_setopt($curl,
>   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
>     $raw_json = curl_exec($curl);
>     curl_close($curl);
>
> /* STEP 3: Parse the JSON auth_info
>   response */   $auth_info =
>   json_decode($raw_json, true);
>
> if ($auth_info['stat'] == 'ok') {
>       /* STEP 3 Continued: Extract the 'identifier' from the response */
>       $profile = $auth_info['profile'];
>       $identifier = $profile['identifier'];
>   $profile['identifier'];
>       if (isset($profile['photo']))  {
>        $photo_url = $profile['photo'];
>       }
>
> ```
> if (isset($profile['displayName']))  {
>   $name = $profile['displayName'];
> }
> ```
>
> if (isset($profile['email']))  {
>         $email = $profile['email'];
>       }
>                 /* Step 5, Check if user existis in database, if so login, if
>   not create new user then login*/ 
>     global $bbdb;   $querystr = " 
>     SELECT *    FROM $bbdb->bb_users
>     WHERE user_email = $email       LIMIT
>   1";   $rtx_user_id =
>   $bbdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
>     print_r($rtx_user_id);
>       if ($rtx_user_id) { 
>       echo "Great success";
>       wp_set_auth_cookie( (int) $rtx_user_id, 0 );  // 0 = don't
>   remember, short login, todo: use form
>   value     do_action('bb_user_login',
>   (int) $rtx_user_id );         }   if
>   (!$rtx_user_id) { echo "Not great
>   success";}
>
> ```
> /* STEP 6: Use the identifier as the unique key to sign the user into
> ```
>
> your system.
>          This will depend on your website implementation, and you should
>   add your own
>          code here.
>       */
>
> /* an error occurred */ }
>
> else {    // gracefully handle the
>   error.  Hook this into your native
>   error handling system.   echo 'An
>   error occured: ' .
>   $auth_info['err']['msg']; } } } ?>

The problem accrues in Step 5 which is to check if the user exists.

Thanks in advance,
Marten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talked on twitter, the query line should be

```
$querystr = "SELECT * FROM $bbdb->users WHERE user_email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: glad that you figured it out :)